# Ruby replacing word

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to replace word in string. I have example string:

```
"aaa bbb, aaacc ccc"
```

And when I try to replace using gsub:

```
string.gsub("aaa", "xxx")
```

I will get "xxx bbb, xxxcc ccc" but I need to change only whole words. I would like to get something like this:

```
"xxx bbb, aaacc ccc"
```

Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

```
a.gsub(/\baaa\b/, "xxx")
```